# Is it possible to apply different colors to terminal tabs in GNOME based on the opened directory?

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

**Is it possible to apply different colors to terminal tabs in GNOME based on the opened directory?**

e.g.

having red background for tab when it is open in:

```
/path/one/*
```

and the green one when tab is in:

```
/path/two/*
```

Comment: gnome-terminal does not support custom *tab* colors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, if you're willing to subvert the `cd` builtin.

Here (from my `~/.bashrc`) is how I put my Username, Host and Current directory in my window title:

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [[ $TERM = xterm ]] || [[ $TERM = xterm-color ]]  && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

Replace the `update_title` function with one of your own to look at the current directory and Do the Right Thing.

Comment: ... And what would be "the Right Thing" to change the tab color?